# java - Distinguish between multiple WebServiceExceptions?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, exception, soap

I have an external API that makes a web service call and can throw two exceptions which I would like to handle differently from each other:

1. `com.sum.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException` - when the web service server doesn't exist
2. `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.soap.DeserializationException` - when the response is a badly formed XML

When I try to catch these exceptions explicitly my Ant compilier says "package does not exist". On some forum I read you shouldn't call sun packages in your code and instead should catch `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException`. This indeed compiles but how can I distinguish between the two exceptions to handle them differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do like this:

```
//...
} catch (WebServiceException e){
    String name = e.getClass().getSimpleName();
    if(name.equals("ClientTransportException")){
        //do what you want
    } else if (name.equals("DeserializationException")){
        //do something else
    }

}
```